# Mongodb shuts down everytime showing exit status 1

Tags: mongodb

thanks for being here, to be fair I do have a solution, but its a temporary one. Its repetitive and kinda annoying doing it everytime you switch on your pc. So if someone has a more permanent solution to this, please upload it here.

The error looks like this:

```
`MongoDB shell version v4.4.6
 connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/? 
 compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: 
 SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection 
 refused :
 connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
 @(connect):2:6
 exception: connect failed
 exiting with code 1`
```

To those facing the same problem, I would add the temporary solution in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

the temporary solution is,
do this after a "sudo su":

```
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

sudo service mongod restart
```